# Algoritmo de Planificación Round Robin

Tags: java, algoritmos

Buenas a todos, tratare de ser lo mas breve posible, busco ayuda para codificar el algoritmo de planificación de procesos "Round Robin (RR)", no se como empezar o que debo de utilizar para este tipo de programa. Busco que el programa haga esto: el usuario debe introducir el tiempo de ejecución de cada proceso y el programa calculara el promedio de los tiempos de ejecución de todos los procesos que el usuario introdujo, lo cual vendría siendo el Quantum, y después comenzar con lo que el algoritmo indica. Espero y alguien pueda ayudarme. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jorge. Favor de brindar la implementación que has hecho y mencionarnos los problemas que tienes. Si buscas que te hagan o te indiquen implementaciones desde cero, es como hacerte la tarea o el trabajo y eso está fuera del alcance del sitio. Te sugiero seleccionar la opción [edit] para agregar estos detalles en tu pregunta. Así mismo, revisar el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: El problema en si es que no se como empezar, obviamente no quiero que me hagan la tarea, solo busco un empujón o una idea de como comenzar, pero tienes razón, agradezco tu observación, investigare mas del tema para facilitarle la ayuda a otras personas